# Executing bash function from file

Tags: bash, functions

I have a bash file with a few functions in it.  Is it possible to run a function from the file using the command line?

Comment: `source` the file to load the functions into your current environment.

Comment: From my terminal? Can one run without sourcing?

Comment: Just testing some new functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your script file so it defines some functions, and run the function given as the first parameter `$1`. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function1() {
  do whatever ...
}

function2() {
  do whatever ...
}

case "$1" in
  function1)    # this is the name of the argument triggering the function - could be different, for instance f1
    function1   # this is the name of the function to run
    ;;

  function2)    # this is the name of the argument triggering the function - could be different, for instance f2
    function2   # this is the name of the function to run
    ;;

  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {function1|function2}"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Interesting.  Would I just pass the name of the function as argument?  Assuming the actual function does not accept any arguments, I suppose.

Comment: Yes. You could also pass another argument as an alias - I inserted some comments to explain. The `case` statement simply says: If the argument is this, then run that function.

Comment: I like it,  It would be convenient to be able to pass any arguments to the respective function.  Would need to eliminate the first argument.

Comment: You could also pass the second argument to the function. I would suggest you look up some bash programming tutorials to dig further into this.